# Delete first 10 characters of every line in textfile

Tags: text-processing, sed, cut, text

Suppose I have a file, `test.java`

It starts off like this **every line**

```
/*     */ package com.a;
/*     */ import java.util.List

/*     */ etc
```

I want to remove the first 10 characters from every line **and replace with empty space**, so after running the command, the file should look like this:

```
package com.a;
import java.util.List

etc
```

**NOT THIS**:

```
          package com.a;
          import java.util.List

          etc
```

Thank you

I'm looking for the correct command, and the command should cover **every single** `.java` file in all subdirectories below.

Comment: Note that it's safer to remove every empty commentary at the beginning of a line (regexp `^/\* *\*/`) instead of blindly removing the first 10 characters. Even if you are sure that all lines in all files start this way. If you accidently start the script twice, all your code will be ruined.

Comment: @Kusalananda I know I use stack exchange frequently, I am familiar with the rules. It's just that I didn't come on the rest of the day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assured about *the first 10 characters* - use the following **`find`** + **`sed`** solution:

```
find . -type f -name "*.java" -exec sed -i 's/.\{10\}//' {} \;
```

---

- `find . -type f -name "*.java"` - to find all `*.java` files recursively
- `sed -i 's/.\{10\}//'` - remove the 1st 10 characters from each line in each found file (`-i` option allows to modify the file *in-place*)
- this solution will work with GNU `sed`. With BSD `sed` you need `-i ''`, as `-i` requires an argument there. With other versions of `sed` you don't have `-i` at all and need to save the output to a different file and `mv` that file to the original name afterwards.

Comment: @KSplitX In this case you are supposed to mark the helpful answer as solution, so future readers will know which answer worked.

Comment: @Philippos I know I didn't come on for the rest of the day

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
sed -i -r 's/.{10}//' *.java
```

Comment: Would I replace `file.txt` with `*.java`?

Comment: Check my edited post

Comment: When I run this in terminal it actually prints the result to the screen but doesnt actually change the file?

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: Anyhow, the question asks to cover all `.java'  files in all subdirectories, so you'll need `find` in addition

Comment: `-r` instead of escape 